# frontend error category products not getting displayed

Tags: frontend, products, category-products, list.phtml, magento2.2.0

I am trying to access the product listing on the frontend

But I am getting this error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\testmastersdirect\mastersdirect.masters-sp.com\shop\app\design\frontend\ASAD\masters\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\list.phtml on line 317
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7ein.png)

[image]

getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');



?>

```
 <div class="quotation-overlay"></div>
    <div class="quotation-popup-modal">
            <div class="close-button"></div>
            <div class="quotation-popup-content-wrapper">
                    <div class="quotation-popup-title">
                            <?php echo __("Request Quote"); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="quotation-popup-details-wrapper">
                            <?php echo __("Product:") ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="quotation-popup-form">
                                    <label for="quotation-message"><?php echo __("Message:"); ?></label>
                                    <textarea name="quotation-message" id="quotation-message"></textarea>
                                    <div class="button-wrapper">
                                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="submit-quotation" class="add-to-bag">
                                            <?php echo __("Request Quote");?>
                                            </a>
                                    </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="quotation-popup-response-wrapper">
                    <?php echo __("Your quotation request was successfully submitted and a copy has been send to you by email. Customer services will contact you shortly.");?>
            </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">

      require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function(jQuery){

       jQuery(".quotation-popup-modal .close-button").on("click", function () {
                    jQuery(".quotation-popup-modal").hide();
                    jQuery(".quotation-overlay").fadeOut();
                    jQuery("body").removeClass("no-scroll");
            });
       jQuery(".quotation-overlay").on("click", function() {
                    jQuery(".quotation-popup-modal").hide();
                    jQuery(".quotation-overlay").fadeOut();
                    jQuery("body").removeClass("no-scroll");

            });


        jQuery('#submit-quotation').on("click", function() {
            var productName = window.currentQuoteProductName;
            var productSKU = window.currentQuoteProductSKU;
            var quoteMessage = jQuery("#quotation-message").val();

            jQuery.ajax({
                    url:"<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl(); ?>quotation_request",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { productname:productName, productsku:productSKU, message:quoteMessage },
                    showLoader: true,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(response){
                            jQuery(".quotation-popup-content-wrapper").hide();
                            if(response !== "success")
                                    jQuery(".quotation-popup-response-wrapper").text("An error occured. Please contact customer services.")
                            jQuery(".quotation-popup-response-wrapper").show();


                        }
                    });
            return false;
            });

   window.openQuoteModal = function(productname, sku) {
        window.currentQuoteProductName = productname;
        window.currentQuoteProductSKU = sku;
        
        jQuery(".quotation-popup-modal .quotation-popup-details-wrapper").text("Product: "+productname);
        console.log('request quote');
                    jQuery(".quotation-popup-modal").show();
                    jQuery(".quotation-overlay").fadeIn();
                    jQuery("body").addClass("no-scroll");

   }

   }); //end require call
        //]]>
```

count()): ?>

```
<div class="message info empty"><div><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('We can\'t find products matching the selection.') ?></div></div>
```

```
<?php echo $block->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
<?php
```

//ADAD-DK always grid
$viewMode = 'grid';
$image = 'category_page_grid';
$hover_image = "category_page_grid_hover";
$showDescription = false;
$templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
/**
* Position for actions regarding image size changing in vde if needed
*/
$pos = $block->getPositioned();
?>

getToolbarHtml() ?>

```
            <?php
            //category search results
            $request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');  
            $param_cat = $request->getParam('cat');
            if($param_cat){
                $category_collection_all = $_product->getCategoryIds();
                if (!in_array($param_cat, $category_collection_all)) {
                                continue;

                }
            }
            
            
                //category search results
            ?>
                <div class="product-item" data-container="product-grid">
                    
                    <?php
                    //Normal Image
                    $productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $image);
                 
                        
                    ?>
                    <div class="product-item-col1">
                    
                    
                        <?php // Product Image ?>
                        <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo" tabindex="-1">
                            <?php echo str_replace('img','img class="normal-image"',$productImage->toHtml()) ?>
                            <?php echo $hoverImageHtml ?>
                        </a>
                        <div class="product-text">
                            <?php
                                $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true);
                            ?>
                            <div class="product-name">
                                <a class="product-item-link"
                                   href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); ?>
                                </a>
                                <?php if($_product->getFulfilmentRegion()): ?>
                                <div class="fulfilment-region">
                                    (<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute("fulfilment_region")->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);?>)
                                </div>
                                
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <div class="fulfilment-region">
                                        (USA)
                                    </div>
                                    
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                            <!--icons-->
                            <div class="product-icons-wrapper">
                             <?php 
                                       
                                ?>
                                    <?php 
                                    $attr =  $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('masters_icons')->getFrontEnd()->getValue( $_product);
                                    if($attr):
                                    
                                        $attr_array = explode(",", $attr);
                                        foreach($attr_array as $icon) :
                                                $img_src = strtolower($icon);
                                                
                                                $img_src = trim($img_src);
                                                
                                                //Make alphanumeric (removes all other characters)
                                                $img_src = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/", "", $img_src);
                                                //Clean up multiple dashes or whitespaces
                                                $img_src = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $img_src);
                                                //Convert whitespaces and underscore to dash
                                                $img_src = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $img_src);          
                                                
                                            ?>
                                            <div class="icon-wrapper"><img src="<?php echo $IMG_PATH.$img_src.'.jpg'; ?>" /></div>
                                    <?php endforeach;
                                    endif;
                                ?>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end icons -->
                            <!--Attributes-->
                            <div class="product-attributes">
                                <?php if($_product->getMasters_manufacturer()): ?>
                                <?php echo $_product->getMasters_manufacturer(); ?> <br />
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if($_product->getMasters_ndc()){ ?>
                                        <?php echo 'NDC: '. $_product->getMasters_ndc();?> <br />
                                <?php } ?>
                                <?php if($_product->getMasters_upc()){ ?>
                                        <?php echo 'UPC: '. $_product->getMasters_upc();?><br />
                                <?php } ?>

                                <?php if($_product->getPipCode()){ ?>
                                        <?php echo $_product->getPipCode();?><br />
                                <?php } ?>

                                
                                <?php if($_product->getActiveIngredient()): ?>
                                <?php echo  $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('active_ingredient')->getFrontEnd()->getLabel(); ?>: <?php echo $_product->getActiveIngredient(); ?><br />
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if($_product->getMastersDf()): ?>
                                <?php echo  $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('masters_df')->getFrontEnd()->getLabel(); ?>: <?php echo $_product->getMastersDf(); ?><br />
                                <?php endif;        ?>
                                
                                <?php if( $_product->getEdiPacksize()): ?>
                                <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('edi_packsize')->getFrontEnd()->getLabel();?>: <?php echo $_product->getEdiPacksize();?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php echo 'MSP: '. $_product->getSku(); ?><br />
                            </div>
                            <div class="product-price tablet mobile">
                             <?php echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="add-to-bag-wrapper mobile">
                                 <!--REAL ADD TO CART MECHANISM-->
            <?php
                $controlledAttribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('controlled_product');
                $controlledProduct = 0;
                if($controlledAttribute) {
                    if("Magento\Framework\Phrase" == get_class($controlledAttribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)))
                        $controlledProduct = $controlledAttribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)->getText() == "Yes";
                    else
                        $controlledProduct = $controlledAttribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
                }
            ?>
                            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && !$controlledProduct): ?>
                                    <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                                    <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post">

                                    <div class="quantity">
                                        <!-- <input type="text" name="qty" class="input-text qty" value="1"/> -->
                                        <input class="input-text qty mod" type="number" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="1">
                                    </div>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
                                        <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
                                        <button class="add-to-cart action tocart" type="submit"
                                                title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add')); ?>"
                                               >
                                        <?php
                                       
                                        $stockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');
                                        $stockQuantity = $stockState->getStockQty($_product->getId(), $_product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
                                        $i = 0;
                                        if($stockQuantity == 0){
                                            $i = 1;
                                            $buttonTitle = __('Request'); 
                                        }else{
                                            $i = 2;
                                            $buttonTitle = __('   Add'); 
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                            <span>
                                            <?php if($i == 2){ ?>
                                                <i class="fa fa-cart-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            <? } ?>

                                            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle; ?></span>
                                        </button>
                                    </form>

                            <!--END ADD TO CART MECH-->
                                    <?php else: ?>
                            <!--Enquiry Trigger-->
```

getName(); ?>','getSku();?>');">

```
                            <!--Enquiry Trigger End-->
                                <?php endif; ?>

                            </div>
                            <div class="quantity-available mobile">
                            <?php
                                                     $StockQuantity = $StockState->getStockQty($_product->getId(), $_product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
                            ?>
                                <?php echo __("Quantity Available")?>: <?php echo $StockQuantity; ?> 
                            </div>
                        
                            <!--Attributes-->
                            <!--Hide product function container-->
                            <div><?php echo $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product); ?></div>
                        </div>
                    </div><?php //end col1 ?>
                    <div class="product-item-col2">
                        <div class="product-price">
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-item-col3">
                   <!--REAL ADD TO CART MECHANISM-->
                            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && !$controlledProduct): ?>
                            <?php
                                   //real
                                    $stockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');
                                    $stockQuantity = $stockState->getStockQty($_product->getId(), $_product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
                                    $i = 0;    
                                    if($stockQuantity == 0){
                                        $i = 1;
                                        $buttonTitle = __('Request'); 
                                    }else{
                                        $i = 2;
                                        $buttonTitle = __('   Add'); 
                                    }
                                    ?>

                                    <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                                    <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post">

                                    <div class="quantity">
                                        <!-- <input type="number" name="qty" class="input-text qty" value="1"/> -->

                                        <input class="input-text qty mod" type="number" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="1">
                                    </div>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="requesttype" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle; ?>">
                                        <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
                                        <button class="add-to-cart action tocart" type="submit"
                                                title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add')); ?>"
                                               >
                                   
                                            <span>
                                            <?php if($i == 2){ ?>
                                                <i class="fa fa-cart-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            <? } ?>
                                            

                                            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle; ?></span>
                        
                                        </button>
                    <div class="quantity-available 11"> 
                    <?php echo __("Quantity Available");?>: <?php echo $StockQuantity;?>
                    </div>
                    <div id='error-validation-clearall' style='color:red' class='error_validation-cartcustom-<?php echo $_product->getId();?>'></div>
                                    </form>
                                 
                            <!--END ADD TO CART MECH-->
                <?php else: ?>
            <!--Enquiry Trigger-->
        <button class="add-to-cart quote" type="submit" onclick="openQuoteModal('<?php echo $_product->getName(); ?>','<?php echo $_product->getSku();?>');">
            <span><?php echo __("Request Quote"); ?></span>
        </button>
            
            <!--Enquiry Trigger End-->
                <?php endif; ?> 
                    </div>

                      
                    
                </div><!--end product-item-->
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        
    </div><!-- end product-list-table -->
</div>
    
    
</div><!-- end product-grid-->
<!--Pager for infinite scroll-->
<div style="display:none;"><?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?></div>
<?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {}
        }
    }
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: seems like you do not have a starting "if():"

Comment: Please share full code. I think somewhere if closing tag is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Comment That line like this one :

```
<?php //else: ?>
```

Then clear the cache and then check.

Answer (score 0):

Check at line: 274 replace with:

```
if($controlledAttribute) {
                            if("Magento\Framework\Phrase" == get_class($controlledAttribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product))):
                                $controlledProduct = $controlledAttribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)->getText() == "Yes";
                            else:
                                $controlledProduct = $controlledAttribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
                            endif;
                        }
```